# Ruby on Rails: Duplicates with Join

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am working on part of an app that will sort a list of children based on their parent's other children's attributes.

Here are the classes I'm working with:

```
class SpecialChild
  belongs_to: Parent

class Child_A
  belongs_to: Parent

class Child_B
  belongs_to: Parent

class Parent
  has_many: SpecialChild
  has_many: Child_A
  has_one: Child_B
```

These are the two order functions that are applied to it:

```
scope :order_child_a,
  joins("INNER JOIN child_a ON specialchild.parent_id = child_a.parent_id").
  where("booleanvalue = true")

scope :order_parent_and_child_b,
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN parent ON specialchild.parent_id = parent.id").
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN child_b AS name ON parent.child_b_id = child_b.id").
  order("name ASC, parent.lastname ASC")
```

My problem is that even though there is only one SpecialChild in this list yet its Parent has multiple Child_A's that have booleanvalue = true, so I get copies of the same SpecialChild showing up even if it doesn't exist.

EDIT:
The problem arises in the first scope though I included the second one because I cannot do a .uniq without hitting more errors because of missing expected information. I also would like to avoid modifying order_parent_and_child_b as it is used throughout the entire app.

Comment: You have to be more specific. Is your problem in the first scope or the second? Or both? Also you may have a typo at the end of the INNER JOIN in the first scope. You have "child.parent_id" but I think you meant "child_a.parent_id" right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me forgetting how SQL works. Needed to distinctly select whatever you order by. So I needed to edit the `scope :order_parent_and_child_b` right after the second `joins()` method.

```
scope :order_parent_and_child_b,
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN parent ON specialchild.parent_id = parent.id").
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN child_b AS name ON parent.child_b_id = child_b.id").
  select("specialchild.*, name.name, parent.lastname").
  order("name.name ASC, parent.lastname ASC")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand it correctly but maybe you can avoid this issue by simply specifying the name of the table inside the where clause, like this:

```
scope :order_child_a,
  joins("INNER JOIN child_a ON specialchild.parent_id = child_a.parent_id").
  where("specialchild.booleanvalue = true")
```

Comment: The booleanvalue is stored under child_a. And just for more clarification, I have one SpecialChild that I want to show in a table if there is a sibling Child_A who has booleanvalue as true. This works find when there is only one Child_A who has the same parent and booleanvalue as true, but any more than that duplicates of the same SpecialChild will show up in the table.